# WiMax technology

Tags: internet, isp

Does WiMax technology is used by an ISP for providing cellular internet services?

Are WiMax technology different from cellular technology for providing internet? Please mention the difference if there are any.

If they are different then what technology used by ISP ?

Comment: Very different from what?

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I have just edited. Please check.

Comment: Removed the questions that are too broad to answer here.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WiMax is used for WAN access by some ISPs. It's not used for cellular services, only for cellular backhaul.

WiMax is somewhat similar to Wi-Fi but has carrier features and much longer reach. It's completely different from traditional cellular services, the differences would most likely fill a book.

For a start, you can find overviews here

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LTE_(telecommunication)
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiMAX

and primers and standards here

- http://www.ieee802.org/16/
- https://www.3gpp.org/technologies/technologies

What technology an ISP uses is entirely up to them. Technologies like WiMax and WLL are in some use, Wi-Fi is also used for short range and hotspot coverage.

Comment: Please mention the basic difference .

Comment: @noviceprogrammer, the difference is simply too great to deal with on a site such as this site. You can get the basic operation of each from the standards bodies that maintain each technology, and they _are_ different standards bodies.

Comment: Not any more... As I recall, Sprint, through their purchase of Clear, briefly had phones on WiMax. But all of that was replaced with LTE. ("Spark" LTE on the Clear 2.5GHz spectrum)

Answer (score 1):

WiMAX is broadband technology to provide wirelessly access to layer 1 (physical) and MAC layer.

It has been used to provide broadband access to user on wireless (like wifi by on larger distance).

Regarding voice service, it's bit challenging due to higher Latency (around 60ms ~ 70ms) compared to normal cellular network.

I remembered there was a time when WiMAX had touched 20milion subscriber

http://wimaxforum.org/Page/News/PR/20110816_WiMAX_Subscriptions_Surpass_20_Million_Globally